# Selenium Python submit() error: stale-element-reference-exception

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

```
a=webdriver.Chrome()

a.get("C:/Users/html_code_03_02.html")

select1=a.find_element(By.NAME,"numReturnSelect")


option2=Select(select1)


for i in range(len(option2.options)):

    option2.select_by_index(i)
    time.sleep(2)
    submit1 = a.find_element(By.NAME, "continue")
    print(submit1)
    submit1.submit()

a.close()
```

It goes inside the for loop and after that the index is selected but once it reaches submit1 it fails

Everytime it should iterate through the loop for each index and it should click on submit which is not happening

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `WebDriverWait` , I guess this will solve your issue.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
a = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
a.get("C:/Users/html_code_03_02.html")

select1 = a.find_element(By.NAME,"numReturnSelect")
option2 = Select(select1)

for i in range(len(option2.options)):
    option2.select_by_index(i)
    WebDriverWait(a, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "continue")))
    submit1 = a.find_element(By.NAME, "continue")
    print(submit1)
    submit1.submit()

a.close()
```